# signal/slot does not get disconnected in PyQt5

Tags: pyqt, pyside

In the following snippet, `PyQt5` behaves different from `PyQt4` and `PySide`. In `PyQt5` when you press the button, 'None' is printed to the console, which means the signal was not disconnected when the widget was deleted. In `PyQt4` and `PySide` everything is fine and nothing is printed out, i.e. the signal got disconnected. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? I have `PyQt5 v5.7.0`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets  # for PyQt5
#from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui  # for PyQt4
#from PySide import QtCore, QtGui  # for PySide
#QtWidgets = QtGui  # for PySide and PyQt4

class MyWidget(QtCore.QObject):
    def doChange(self):
        print(self)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
w = MyWidget()
button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Push me")
button.clicked.connect(w.doChange)
del w
button.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

UPDATE: Moreover this issue is observable only on Linux. Windows seems to work fine. Seems this is a bug.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Calling `del` from Python is generally not needed unless you have a very special use case. It looks like Qt should handle disconnects when the underlying object is deleted so what you posted should probably work.

Comment: no, this is just simplification, I do not use `del` directly of course. in my application I have something like: create a widget, connect it to some signal, then use this widget somehow, then remove this widget a replace it with another widget, connect the new one, use the new one, replace it by yet another one, etc. the trouble is that all the removed (and deleted) widgets remain connected to the signal.

Comment: @V.K. I cannot reproduce this on linux. But in any case, your test case is pretty useless as it not representative of your real application. You need to provide some realistic example code that shows exactly how you are create the widgets, how you connect the signals, and how you delete the widgets.

Comment: The real application works like this: in the main window, the user can open a file, some widgets are created to display the contents of the file and allow some user interaction. One of the widgets gets connected with a signal (as above). Then the user can close the file which will delete all the widgets except the main window. Then the user can open another file which in turn will create new widgets and one of them is again connected to the signal. But the problem is that the signal is not disconnected from the previously deleted widgets.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is with the bugged PyQt 5.7.0 version. Hoping 5.7.1 will be bug free. :)

Comment: @V.K. There's nothing stopping you from trying the latest development snapshot. If it's not been fixed already, you'll need to report it on the mailing list - but you'd need a proper test case for that. As I say, I cannot reproduce this on Linux using PyQt-5.7 - so there's no bug, AFAIKS.